# Open Magmi from Admin Dashboard plus ACL

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi, permissions, acl

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0 and Magmi 0.7.18.

I'm opening Magmi (with login and password) using url like this :

```
http://example.com/my-importer/web/magmi.php
```

How to open Magmi as a menu in the admin menu and adding user rules (ACL) in it ?

Comment: You cannot out of the box. I guess Magmi could be extended to read ACL values pretty easily. Right now it just lets you use the magento access.

Comment: Alternatively you can roll your own Magento extension that wraps magmi's API. Like these people did; http://www.magelynx.com/shop/import-export-plugin.html